# Prove Laplace's equation is rotation invariant

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Prove that Laplace's equation $\Delta u = 0$ is rotation invariant; that is, if $O$ is an orthogonal $n\times n$ matrix and we define

$$       v(x) := u(Ox) \quad (x \in \mathbb{R}^n)$$
then $\Delta v = 0$.

I wanted to see if what I had below was correct and complete. Any feedback on rigor is greatly appreciated.

In cartesian coordinates, we have $\Delta u = \sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_i^2}$. Letting the $i$th row and $j$th column of the matrix $O$ be $a_{ij}$ we have

\begin{equation}
 \frac{\partial v}{\partial x_j} = \sum_{i =1}^n\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}a_{ij}
\end{equation}

Thus,
\begin{equation}
 \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x_j^2} = \sum_{i =1}^n\sum_{k = 1}^n\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_i\partial x_k}a_{ij}a_{kj}
\end{equation}

Therefore:
\begin{align}
\Delta v &= \sum_{j = 1}^n \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x_j^2}\\
    &= \sum_{j = 1}^n \left(\sum_{i =1}^n\sum_{k = 1}^n\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_i\partial x_k}a_{ij}a_{kj}\right)\\
    &= \sum_{i =1}^n\sum_{k = 1}^n\left(\sum_{j = 1}^n \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_i\partial x_k}a_{ij}a_{kj}\right)\\
    &= \sum_{i =1}^n\sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_i\partial x_k}\left(\sum_{j = 1}^na_{ij}a_{kj}\right)\\
    &=\sum_{i =1}^n\sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_i\partial x_k}\delta_{i, k}\\
    &= \sum_{i =1}^n\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_i^2} = 0
\end{align}

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2753213/prove-that-the-lalpaces-equation-delta-u-0-is-rotation-invariant-on-bf-r?rq=1).

Comment: Its "correct" in so much as a "proof" is merely a calculation without explanatory words (by which I mean, more words would be nice)

Answer (score 3):

A coordinate-free proof uses that $\triangle u = {\rm tr}(D\nabla u)$, where $\nabla u:\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^n$ is the gradient function of $u$ and the linear map $D(\nabla u)(x):\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^n$ is the Hessian of $u$ at $x$.

The chain rule says that $$\langle \nabla(u\circ O)(x) ,v\rangle = D(u\circ O)(x)(v) = Du(Ox)\circ DO(x)(v) = Du(Ox)(Ov) = \langle \nabla u(Ox),Ov\rangle = \langle O^\top \nabla u(Ox),v\rangle,$$ so $\nabla(u\circ O)(x) = O^\top \nabla u(Ox)$. Apply $D$ to get $$D\nabla (u\circ O)(x)(v) = O^\top D\nabla u(Ox)O(v).$$ Thus $$\triangle(u\circ O)(x) = {\rm tr}(O^\top D\nabla u(Ox) O) = {\rm tr}(OO^\top D\nabla u(Ox)) = {\rm tr}(D\nabla u(Ox)) = (\triangle u)(Ox),$$by cyclic invariance of trace and $OO^\top = {\rm Id}$. So $\triangle(u\circ O) = (\triangle u)\circ O$. The conclusion is that $u$ is harmonic if and only if $u\circ O$ is harmonic for one (and hence every) orthogonal map $O$.